# How can one separate a literal block from a blockquote in restructuredtext?

Tags: restructuredtext

For example if I have:

```
.. code:: python
   import os
   this_is_the_last_code_line = 5

   Now I want this text to be a blockquote.
```

The blockquote is assumed to be part of the literal code block. Is there some way to indicate that these are separate blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`pull-quote` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#pull-quote).

```
.. code:: python

    import os
    this_is_the_last_code_line = 5

.. pull-quote::

    Now I want this text to be a blockquote.
```